# XNA - Converting a Texture2D[,] to a Texture2D

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xna

I'm currently working with 2D blocks, which I've used to create some tetris figures using a matrix(Texture2D[,]).

Now I would like to draw my Texture2D[,] using the XNA .draw method, but it obviously only accepts pure Texture2D. I need to draw my objects as an array, so I can return to the single squares later in the program.

Comment: What is preventing you from drawing the textures one at a time?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just need a nested `for` loop:

```
for (int i; i  < MAX_INDEX1; i++)
{
    for (int j; j < MAX_INDEX2; j++
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture2DCollection[i, j], rectangle, Color.White);
    }
}
```